# Trying to figure out a Mathematical pattern

Tags: fractions, pattern-recognition

I am given a start point, *a*, an end point *b*, and a number of values *x*. With that I am supposed to come up with the points between the start and end point. Below is an example

```
Given a = 1/2, b = 17/3, and x = 5

1/2
43/24
37/12
38/8
17/3
```

That list is the answer to the question. I tried figuring this out and looking for a algorithm to do this and found each number differs by *31/24* which I can call *y*.

My question is, how do I get those middle numbers or better yet, find my *y*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a pattern is called an arithmetic progression ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)).

If you're looking for an arithmetic progression $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_x$ of length $x$  starting from $p_1=a$ and ending at $p_x=b$, the common difference $y$ you're looking for is
$$y=\frac{b-a}{x-1}$$
That way, you get
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
i & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & x\\\hline
p_i & a & a+1\left(\frac{b-a}{x-1}\right) & a+2\left(\frac{b-a}{x-1}\right) & \cdots & \underbrace{a+(x-1)\left(\frac{b-a}{x-1}\right)}_{\Large =\;b}
\end{array}$$